# Suppress *some* URLs with biblatex nature.bbx class

Tags: biblatex, urls

I am using a Nature biblatex style with bibtex to typeset bibliography and would like to suppress URLs from appearing in the "paper" entry types (like books, journal articles and proceedings). If I use url=none, URLs are suppressed everywhere, including the online resources. I need to avoid it. Is there a way?

**Update**
I use Mendeley to manage bibliography. These are two @book examples from the bib-file:

```
@book{SnyderLove1983,
  address = {London},
  author = {Snyder, Allan and Love, John},
  publisher = {Chapman \& Hall},
  title = {{Optical waveguide theory}},
  url = {http://books.google.com/books?id=gIQB\_hzB0SMC},
  year = {1983}
}

@book{Agrawal01,
  author = {Agrawal, Govind P.},
  edition = {3rd},
  pages = {467},
  publisher = {Academic Press},
  series = {Optics and Photonics},
  title = {{Nonlinear Fiber Optics}},
  url = {http://www.elsevierdirect.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780120451432},
  year = {2001}
}
```

This is @inproceedings:

```
@inproceedings{Liao2011,
  author = {Liao, Changrui and Wang, Dongming and He, Xiaoying and Yang, Minwei},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of SPIE},
  doi = {10.1117/12.885826},
  number = {13},
  pages = {77534I--77534I--4},
  title = {{Twisted optical microfiber for refractive index sensing}},
  url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?PSISDG/7753/77534I/1 http://link.aip.org/link/PSISDG/v7753/i1/p77534I/s1\&Agg=doi},
  volume = {23},
  year = {2011}
}
```

In the @inproceedings record, Mendeley has concatenated two URLs in the bib-file. A bug, clearly.

Comment: URLs should be automatically missed out if papers have pages: this is by far the most common place to see a URL stored but not needed when printed.  Perhaps you could provide an example of your `.bib` file?

Comment: @JosephWright: I added a couple of book records to the original question. One with pages, another without. Both are typeset with URL. Same with inproceedings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is difficult to handle within a style as it depends on how people store data in their database. (Different users will have different ideas about which types should and should not include a URL.) However, within a document it should be easy enough to handle using `biblatex`'s abilities to access the data model. For example, something like

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {\clearfield{url}}
    {}%
}
```

will clear the URL field for all books. Using a boolean expression, this can then be extended for multiple entry types

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr
    {
      test { \ifentrytype{book} }
      or
      test { \ifentrytype{inbook} }
      or
      test { \ifentrytype{inproceedings} }
    }
    {\clearfield{url}}
    {}%
}
```

Comment: @texnic I've updated the bool expression: try the new one

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for. Both solutions work, thank you!