# biblatex cite urls only if no page number is present

Tags: biblatex, urls

Analogous to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154864/biblatex-use-doi-only-if-there-is-no-url) question, is there a way to show `url`s only for those references that do not have `pages`?

In my bibliography I have a number of articles or reviews where I keep the url field to know which website I got a given pdf from, but the pdf is a regularly published article, so it has page numbers, hence the `url` information is redundant. However, I also have *some* `@article`s from regular online journals and therefore not of the `@online` type, but that don't have pages where I would need to keep the `url`.

In short, I don't want to eliminate urls [globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46787/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-urls-from-appearing-in-biblatex-citations) or [per bibtex type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59608/suppress-some-urls-with-biblatex-nature-bbx-class), but rather have some if-then function do it for me based on whether or not the `pages` field is empty.

**EDIT**: It would also be great to accomplish the same for `doi` and `urldate` fields, i.e., suppress these too if page numbers are present.

Following the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154864/biblatex-use-doi-only-if-there-is-no-url) one could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=pages,final]
      \step[fieldset=url,null]
    }  
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  author = {Antelope, Alfred},
  year = {2010},
  title = {A Title},
  url = {www.url.com},
  urldate = {2015-05-05},  
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {3--15}
}
@article{test2,
  author = {Bee, Ben},
  year = {2011},
  title = {Best Title},
  url = {www.url.com},
  urldate = {2015-05-05},  
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

... but it still always prints the `urldate` and, if present, also the `doi` field.  Maybe someone knows a better solution?

Comment: One can certainly remove the fields with a source map. But what will you do if you run into an online journal in pdf format where the article is on page 3? Imho you should better correct your bib-file. If the url is not a real url but only a note to yourself, move it to another field.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Point taken!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend your sourcemapping a bit to also delete `doi`s and `urldate`, if `pages` are present.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=pages,final]
      \step[fieldset=url,null]
      \step[fieldset=urldate,null]
      \step[fieldset=doi,null]
    }  
  }
}
```

With standard `biblatex` styles you could alternatively use

```
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {\iftoggle{bbx:doi}
       {\printfield{doi}}
       {}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
       {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
       {}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iftoggle{bbx:url}
       {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
      {}}
    {}}
```

For `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` the modification is

```
\renewbibmacro*{bib+doi+url}{% 16th ed.
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{urlyear}\AND\iffieldundef{urlmonth}}%
       {}%
       {\printurldate}% Date fix
     \iffieldundef{addendum}%
       {\newunit\newblock}%
       {\newcunit\newblock}%
     \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
       {\iffieldundef{doi}%
          {}%
          {\printfield{doi}%
           \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock%
           \clearfield{url}}}%
       {\ifboolexpr{%
          togl {cms@doi}%
          and
          not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
        }%
          {\printfield{doi}%
           \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock}%
          {}}%
     \ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@eprint}%
       and
       not test {\iffieldundef{eprint}}%
     }%
       {\usebibmacro{eprint}%
        \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock}%
       {}%
     \ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@url}%
       and
       not test {\iffieldundef{url}}%
     }%
       {\printfield{url}}%
       {}}
    {}}%
```

Comment: That's a thorough solution!  Thank you very much!